# foreach loop not showing data when i call it on view page in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5.3

I am having this code in my controller. When i print the variable in view it gives only last row of database table column. How i print all the value as a string on view. Can anyone help please

```
public function welcome(){
    $company_name = DB::table('companies')
            ->select('company_name')
            ->get(); 
    return view('welcome',['company_name' => $company_name]);
}
```

I am trying to access the value in this jquery code

```
 @foreach ($company_name as $company_names)


  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: [
         { value: "{{$company_names->company_name}}", url:        "http://localhost:8000/company_profile" }, 

    ],
    select: function (event, ui) {
        window.location = ui.item.url;
    }
  });
  });
  </script>
```

@endforeach

Comment: Edit your question to show code from your view..

Comment: Is your `$name` an array type variable??? You can use `return view('welcome', ['name' => $value->company_name]); ` intead of `$name = $value->company_name;`

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure you add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only sending a value of the last row to your View.
Doing this might help:

```
//controller
public function welcome(){
     $company_names = DB::table('companies')
        ->select('company_name')
        ->get();
return view('welcome',compact('company_names'));
}
```

Add this code to your View: `welcome.blade.php`

```
//Printing a list of companies in a View
<ul>
@foreach ($company_names as $company_name)
           <li>{{ $company_name->company_name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i already did this and it doesn't work for. Have u tried this 
??

Comment: @princepriyadarshi yes I have and it's working on my side.. After `->get();` try to return `$company_names` to check if it's retrieving data as it should..

Comment: Ok but i did the same but its give only last row value.. And i am passing the variable in jquery code and when i search the only last row value appear in autocomplete not the whole value..

Comment: @princepriyadarshi I need to know what you get when you do this:
     //controller
    public function welcome(){
         $company_names = DB::table('companies')
             ->select('company_name')
             ->get();
     return $company_names;
     return view('welcome',compact('company_names'));
     }

Comment: When I tested the code on my side on a dummy table I got something like:
`[{"name":"Hydrangeas"},{"name":"Jellyfish"},{"name":"Morlern"}]`

Comment: When i do this $name[]=$company_name->company_name the whole value print but in an array. Bt single value as a string is not printing on view.

Comment: For now let's simplify things.. Copy my `View` code and paste it in your view and tell me  what you get..

Comment: @princepriyadarshi edit your question to show all the code from your view.. That is `welcome.blade.php`

Comment: I deleted all the code i am doing only that on my view.. {{$compny_details->company_details}} thas it..

Comment: What you get from your controller is an array of objects; you need to loop through it to get the object one by one.. For example in my answer I have `<ul>
@foreach ($company_names as $company_name)
           <li>{{ $company_name->company_name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>`
As I have suggested before.. Copy the code from my answer as is (only view code part), then add it to your view..

Comment: foreach ($company_names as $company_name)
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: [
             { value: "{{ $company_name->company_name }}", url: "http://localhost:8000/company_profile" }, 
             
        ],
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;
        }
    });
});
  </script>
 
@endforeach

this is where i wanna get my company name in search box. But when i do this it only take the last row value